# Kernel panic Attempted to kill init! - Android kernel on raspberry pi

Tags: android, c, linux

I compiled an Android Linux kernel for **raspberry pi**. The board seems to boot with that kernel but I get the following error when it tries to run /init process.

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

I put debug statements in the code and could find out that a `sys_exit_group` system call is called with exit `code = 4`

```
[Current Situation]: I have copied the contents of out/target/product/generic/root into the RPI SD card (/dev/mmcblk0p6) and also copied systems folder to it.
```

When I tried earlier with the previous arch linux root `filesystem` on the SD card, this error did not seem to come.

Attached below is the log with some of my debug statements too (starting with [Shadman])

```
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1485]:: unshared_files
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1491]:: kzalloc
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1496]:: prepare_bprm_creds
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1501]:: check_unsafe_exec
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[96]: Failed to execute - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_exit[906]:: In fucntion.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]exit_notify[814]:: In Function. [Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[89]: In function - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1476]:: 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[770]:: In function
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]find_new_reaper[707]:: In function.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[782]:: Got reaper father
if ((current->flags & PF_NPROC_EXCEEDED) 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1485]:: unshared_files
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1491]:: kzalloc
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1496]:: prepare_bprm_creds
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1501]:: check_unsafe_exec
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[96]: Failed to execute - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_exit[906]:: In fucntion.
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]exit_notify[814]:: In Function. 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[770]:: [Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[89]: In function - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1476]:: 
usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
In function
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]find_new_reaper[707]:: In function.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[782]:: Got reaper father
if ((current->flags & PF_NPROC_EXCEEDED) 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1485]:: unshared_files
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1491]:: kzalloc
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1496]:: prepare_bprm_creds
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1501]:: check_unsafe_exec
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[96]: Failed to execute - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_exit[906]:: In fucntion.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]exit_notify[814]:: In Function. [Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[89]: In function - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1476]:: 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[770]:: In function
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]find_new_reaper[707]:: In function.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[782]:: Got reaper father
if ((current->flags & PF_NPROC_EXCEEDED) 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1485]:: unshared_files
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1491]:: kzalloc
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1496]:: prepare_bprm_creds
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1501]:: check_unsafe_exec
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[96]: Failed to execute - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_exit[906]:: In fucntion.
logger: created 256K log 'log_main'
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]exit_notify[814]:: [Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[89]: In function - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1476]:: In Function. 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[770]:: In function
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]find_new_reaper[707]:: In function.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[782]:: Got reaper father
if ((current->flags & PF_NPROC_EXCEEDED) 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1485]:: unshared_files
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1491]:: kzalloc
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1496]:: prepare_bprm_creds
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1501]:: check_unsafe_exec
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[96]: Failed to execute - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_exit[906]:: In fucntion.
logger: created 256K log 'log_events'
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]exit_notify[814]:: [Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[89]: In function - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1476]:: In Function. 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[770]:: In function
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]find_new_reaper[707]:: In function.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[782]:: Got reaper father
if ((current->flags & PF_NPROC_EXCEEDED) 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1485]:: unshared_files
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1491]:: kzalloc
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1496]:: prepare_bprm_creds
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1501]:: check_unsafe_exec
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[96]: Failed to execute - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_exit[906]:: In fucntion.
logger: created 256K log 'log_radio'
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]exit_notify[814]:: [Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[89]: In function - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1476]:: In Function. 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[770]:: In function
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]find_new_reaper[707]:: In function.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[782]:: Got reaper father
if ((current->flags & PF_NPROC_EXCEEDED) 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1485]:: unshared_files
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1491]:: kzalloc
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1496]:: prepare_bprm_creds
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1501]:: check_unsafe_exec
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[96]: Failed to execute - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_exit[906]:: In fucntion.
logger: created 256K log 'log_system'
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]exit_notify[814]:: [Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[89]: In function - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1476]:: 
usb 1-1: new high speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
In Function. 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[770]:: In function
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]find_new_reaper[707]:: In function.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[782]:: Got reaper father
if ((current->flags & PF_NPROC_EXCEEDED) 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1485]:: unshared_files
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1491]:: kzalloc
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1496]:: prepare_bprm_creds
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1501]:: check_unsafe_exec
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[96]: Failed to execute - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_exit[906]:: In fucntion.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]exit_notify[814]:: In Function. [Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[89]: In function - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1476]:: 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[770]:: In function
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]find_new_reaper[707]:: In function.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[782]:: Got reaper father
if ((current->flags & PF_NPROC_EXCEEDED) 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1485]:: unshared_files
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1491]:: kzalloc
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1496]:: prepare_bprm_creds
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1501]:: check_unsafe_exec
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[96]: Failed to execute - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_exit[906]:: In fucntion.
TCP cubic registered
Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]exit_notify[814]:: In Function. 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[770]:: 
NET: Registered protocol family 17
Registering the dns_resolver key type
VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 1 part 20 variant b rev 5
In function
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]find_new_reaper[707]:: In function.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[782]:: Got reaper father
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[89]: In function - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1476]:: if ((current->flags & PF_NPROC_EXCEEDED) 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1485]:: unshared_files
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1491]:: kzalloc
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1496]:: prepare_bprm_creds
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1501]:: check_unsafe_exec
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[96]: Failed to execute - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_exit[906]:: In fucntion.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]exit_notify[814]:: In Function. [Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[89]: In function - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1476]:: 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[770]:: In function
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]find_new_reaper[707]:: In function.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[782]:: Got reaper father
if ((current->flags & PF_NPROC_EXCEEDED) 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1485]:: unshared_files
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1491]:: kzalloc
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1496]:: prepare_bprm_creds
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1501]:: check_unsafe_exec
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[96]: Failed to execute - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_exit[906]:: In fucntion.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]exit_notify[814]:: In Function. [Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[89]: In function - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1476]:: 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[770]:: In function
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]find_new_reaper[707]:: In function.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[782]:: Got reaper father
if ((current->flags & PF_NPROC_EXCEEDED) 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1485]:: unshared_files
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1491]:: kzalloc
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1496]:: prepare_bprm_creds
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1501]:: check_unsafe_exec
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[96]: Failed to execute - Filename = /sbin/hotplug 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_exit[906]:: In fucntion.
drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]exit_notify[814]:: In Function. 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[770]:: [Shadman] [init/main.c:]kernel_init[859]:: Preparing namespace =====================
[Shadman] [init/main.c:]kernel_init[861]:: In function
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]find_new_reaper[707]:: In function.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[782]:: Got reaper father
sys_access((const char __user *) ramdisk_execute_command, 0) != 0 returned true
[Shadman] [init/do_mounts.c:]prepare_namespace[443]:: In function ==========
[Shadman] [init/do_mounts.c:]prepare_namespace[464]:: saved_root_name[0], /dev/mmcblk0p6
[Shadman] [init/do_mounts.c:]prepare_namespace[477]:: Here ==============
[Shadman] [init/do_mounts.c:]mount_block_root[307]:: In function: /dev/root, 32768 =========
[Shadman] [init/do_mounts.c:]mount_block_root[320]:: In for (p = fs_names; *p; p += strlen(p)+1)
[Shadman] [init/do_mounts.c:]do_mount_root[290]:: In function: /dev/root, ext4, 32768
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p6): recovery complete
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
usb 1-1: device not accepting address 4, error -32
VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:6.
[Shadman] [init/do_mounts.c:]mount_block_root[322]:: do_mount_root() err = 0
[Shadman] [init/main.c:]kernel_init[866]:: Preparing namespace done ====================
[Shadman] [init/main.c:]init_post[769]:: In Function
[Shadman] [init/main.c:]init_post[772]:: Finished: async_synchronize_full()
Freeing init memory: 120K
[Shadman] [init/main.c:]init_post[774]:: Finished: free_initmem()
[Shadman] [init/main.c:]init_post[776]:: Finished: mark_rodata_ro()
[Shadman] [init/main.c:]init_post[780]:: Finished all async init code.
[Shadman] [init/main.c:]init_post[791]:: if (ramdisk_execute_command) is not satisfied
[Shadman] [init/main.c:]init_post[800]:: doing execute_command: /init
[Shadman] [init/main.c:]run_init_process[758]:: process name = /init
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[89]: In function - Filename = /init 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1476]:: if ((current->flags & PF_NPROC_EXCEEDED) 
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1485]:: unshared_files
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1491]:: kzalloc
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1496]:: prepare_bprm_creds
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1501]:: check_unsafe_exec
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1510]:: PTR_ERR(file)
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1513]:: Schedular exec
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1522]:: bprm_mm_init
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1527]:: count
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1532]:: ENV count
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1537]:: prepare_binprm
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1542]:: copy_strings_kernel
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1548]:: copy_strings
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1553]:: copy_strings
[Shadman] [fs/exec.c:]do_execve_common[1558]:: search_binary_handler
[Shadman] [arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c:]kernel_execve[100]: Exec successful. Restoring registers = /init 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_group_exit[1090]:: Group exit with code = 4
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]do_exit[906]:: 
usb 1-1: new high speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
In fucntion.
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]exit_notify[814]:: In Function. 
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]forget_original_parent[770]:: In function
[Shadman] [kernel/exit.c:]find_new_reaper[707]:: In function.
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

Comment: The 5-10 lines _before_ that message should have information about the actual problem. That line by itself doesn't really say much except that there's a problem.

Comment: @Mat As far as I could understand, there isn't much 5-10 lines before this line. The kernel mounts the rootfs and goes to init_post(), calls a few more functions with out error and calls run_init_process("/init") to start /init.

Comment: Messages in the log, not code lines.

Comment: Your init process died, or couldn't be started. So your problem is in your configuration, not the code.